# Time tracking while Video playing in Android

Tags: android

I want to display a button at particular point of time whenever a video plays in android studio,so how would I track the video playing time

Comment: Do you have any working code you can add to the question?

Comment: I have done this so far,

Answer (score 0):

```
  public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
                mVideoView2.start();
                loadJSONFromAsset();
                duration = mVideoView2.getDuration();
                current = mVideoView2.getCurrentPosition();
                // TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView_currentPosion);
                textCurrentPosition.setText(String.valueOf(current));
                //textCurrentPosition.setText(duration);
                Log.d("Current Location", String.valueOf(current));
                if (current > 2000 && current < 9000) {

                    buttonPause.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


                } else {
                    buttonPause.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: The value of current is always 0,as it enters onPrepared function only initially.But I need to track the time for an interval.